# Consulta fechas Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

Necesito ayuda con una consulta lo que quiero es que necesito calcular los meses de un trabajador de una empresa y sumarlos con todos los demás contratos que tuvo.

EJ: Si comenzó a trabajar en una fecha como **15/06/2016** hasta **15/06/2018** (24 meses), pero si de repente decidió retirarse de esa empresa y luego más tarde decidió volver y ahora tiene un contrato del 16/04/2018 hasta 16/04/2019 (12 meses) necesito sumar todos esos meses para cada trabajador (36 meses). sería de mucha ayuda su respuesta gracias.

Esto es lo que tengo pero no logro concretar lo que necesito:

```
<?php 

            $query=$obj->post_ejecutar("SELECT * FROM datoscontractuales WHERE estado NOT IN (4, 5, 6)");

            while ($row=pg_fetch_array($query)) {

                $años=(strtotime($row["fecinicio"])-strtotime($row["fecfin"]))/(30*60*60*24);
                //La función abs lo que hace es sacar el valor absoluto de el valor recibido
                $años=abs($años); 
                //Redondea un número decimal
                $años=floor($años);

                echo $años;

            }


?>
```

Comment: Y como lo hago?

Comment: Puedo compartir solo el link de la bd de solo esa tabla?

Comment: porque no pegas la estructura minima que se necesita, algunos valores que tiene y lo que te retorna

Comment: Puedo ponerte una imagen?

Comment: Este enlace puede ayudarte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012629/count-months-between-two-timestamp-on-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Pues utilizar las funciones de PostgreSQL age para sacar un intervalo de las fechas, y extract para sacar y calcular los meses, aquí un ejemplo:

Aquí solo se calcula el intervalo:

```
SELECT age('2018-06-15'::date, '2016-02-15'::date);
```

Aquí se extraen los meses:

```
SELECT extract(YEAR FROM age('2018-06-15'::date, '2016-02-15'::date)) * 12 + extract(MONTH FROM age('2018-06-15'::date, '2016-02-15'::date));
```

Ahora también puedes hacer una función que ya te retorne esto:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calcula_meses(fecha_inicio DATE, fecha_fin DATE) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN extract(year FROM age(fecha_fin, fecha_inicio::date)) * 12 + extract(month from age(fecha_fin, fecha_inicio));
    END; $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Así se mandaría a llamar:

```
    SELECT calcula_meses('2016-02-15'::date, '2018-06-15'::date);
```

Saludos!